# Confusion with Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So, I have developed the basics for a litte game... tic tac toe... but i have a problem and I don't know how to solve this in the best way... So I have this:

```
var playfield = function(){
this.board = [
    [null, null, null],
    [null, null, null],
    [null, null, null]
];

this.simulationMode = false;

this.nextSymbol = "X";

this.setSymbol = function(symbol, x, y){
        if(this.whoIsNext() == symbol || this.simulationMode){
            if(this.isFree(x, y)){
                this.board[y][x] = symbol;
                this.changeWhoIsNext();
                return true;
            }else{
                console.log("Field is not empty "+x+";"+y);
                return false;
            }   
        }else{
            console.log("It is not "+symbol+"'s turn");
        }
    };
...
}
```

This stores the gamefield itself.

```
var board1 = new playfield();
```

Then I want to make a new instance the calculate the next moves:

```
var simboard = new playfield();
```

But then I do this:

```
simboard.setSymbol("X", x, y);
```

it makes the changes in board1 and simboard.
Why? And what I'm doing wrong...?

Full source can be found here:
https://gameink.net/js/tictactoe.js?PageSpeed=off

Comment: You have the issue with references to the `this.board` property. You have initialize it in a different way. For example, when creating a new instance of the object.

Comment: Also, doesn't `new new` throw an error?

Comment: Good point, was an copy paste typo.

Comment: You do not have to be sorry for this. I did started as much as possible in OOP.. but then run into this problem and then changed everything... and ... yeah... First real Project in Javascript... so I'm heavily confused. At the moment I only now the basic functionality of Javascript, Functional programming and jQuery... normally I work with PHP... OOP.

Comment: Deleted first comment to not sound like a dick but basicaly:

Try to follow OOP standards and have a read at how to define Classes and Methods in JS. Try to follow ONE Design Pattern and I swear, you won't have this problems any longer!
I threw together some code that will work nicely:
https://pastebin.com/1mh2hqta

Have fun coding!

Comment: I would advise against using classes in JS. As they obsfucate the underlying prototypal nature of JS, and will likely cause issues in the future.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I partly disagree. For basic Webdesign and Events I wouldn't use classes. But if you want to have a game like this having a Structure can be very helpful, as long as you follow your own standart

Comment: @Simon I understand, but I'd still prefer object composition, or even the revealing module pattern. As OOP can lead to nasty inheritance trees.

Comment: @ManuelBecker I can't replicate your issue using a [mcve] (see http://jsbin.com/zunakiy/edit?js,console)